# My useState variable throws cannot read length of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm implementing pagination where I have a useState variable which I change with a change in page number, below is the code where I use two useEffects to call the data of pagenumber and pagenumber+1 to check if it throws a 404 so I know when to stop displaying the next button.

```
useEffect(() => {
    
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const baseUrl = 'https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters';
                const url = baseUrl + '?ts=' + ts + '&apikey=' + publickey + '&hash=' + hash+ '&limit=100&offset='+parseInt(pageNumber)*50;
                const { data } = await axios.get(url);
                setCharactersData(data.data.results);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                setCharactersData([]);
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        
        fetchData();
    }, [ pageNumber ]);


    
    useEffect(() => {
    
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const baseUrl = 'https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters';
                const url = baseUrl + '?ts=' + ts + '&apikey=' + publickey + '&hash=' + hash+ '&limit=100&offset='+(parseInt(pageNumber)+1)*50;
                const { data } = await axios.get(url);
                console.log(data);
                setNewData(data.data.results);
                setLoading(false);
            } catch (e) {
                setNewData([]);
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        
        fetchData();
    }, [ pageNumber ]);
```

Return part:

```
return (
            <div>
                { parseInt(pageNumber)!==0 && <Link className='characterlink1' to={`/characters/page/${parseInt(pageNumber)-1}`}>
                        Previous
                    </Link>}
                    
                    { charactersData.length===0 && <Four />}

                 { newData.length>0 && <Link className='characterlink2' to={`/characters/page/${parseInt(pageNumber)+1}`}>
                        Next
                    </Link>}
```

This was working fine until I added the lines:

1. setCharactersData([]); in catch block of first useEffect.
2. { charactersData.length===0 && } in the return part.

I added these lines to add a 404 page if the url has a pagenumber which is larger than the available pagenumbers. When I do this I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

The weird part is that I don't see this error until I change the url 3-4 times.

Comment: Try to replace`newData.length>0` with`!!newData?.length`

Comment: And the way you organized your codebase doesn't look quite nice - API definition does not belong to component and, probably, should be isolated into separate module.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I made these changes but did not resolve the issue.

Comment: why two `useEffect` with same dependency ? at least you can merge them and by the way most of apis  have an endpoint telling you the number of pages available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing your state in a catch block, which is not how you're supposed to change your state. Instead, I would say it is better to try initialize your state with the empty array so that the `length` property always exists, thus removing the error. Such a thing can be done like this:

```js
const [charactersData, setCharactersData] = useState([]);
```

Or with the type of the charactersData (yay typescript)

```js
const [charactersData, setCharactersData] = useState<charactersDataType>([]);
```

Comment: Hi, this worked, but I still don't understand why my code was not working, I was changing the state only in the catch block which means when there was no data returned from the API.

Comment: Actually that is not true, as that is not the intention behind the catch block. There is a significant difference between catching an error from your request (which is what the catch block does) and your API not returning data. If your API does not throw a 404 to the request, but rather returns an empty array (which is most likely the case), then your catch block is not triggered.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the explanation, but if it returns an empty array it will still have a length of 0 right, why does it throw an error?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your API returns, but it is most likely the case that the `{data}` then does not have either the second `data` or the `results` prop as you use in the `setState` command. Chances are your API returns
`data: []`
whereas you expect:

`data: {data: {results: [....] } }`
Often typing your responses would help in this case, but as you're not using typescript (from what I can see) the best thing you can do is thoroughly inspect all the responses from your API

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you used Pascal casing is used in you fetch blocks and you used camelcasing in the return block..?

```
return (
            <div>
                { parseInt(pageNumber)!==0 && <Link className='characterlink1' to={`/characters/page/${parseInt(pageNumber)-1}`}>
                        Previous
                    </Link>}
                    
                    { CharactersData.length===0 && <Four />}

                 { newData.length>0 && <Link className='characterlink2' to={`/characters/page/${parseInt(pageNumber)+1}`}>
                        Next
                    </Link>}
```

Comment: No that's fine, I have defined it as const [ charactersData, setCharactersData ] = useState(undefined);

Comment: Please don't post further questions or assumptions as answers. The "answer" function is to be used for definite solutions only.